# SFDX bulk upsert, doesn't work even with samples. Field name not found : First Name

Tags: salesforcedx, bulk-api, data-migration

I'm trying to use sfdx bulk api capability, but so fast I'm unsuccessful.

No matter the file I get `InvalidBatch : Field name not found : FirstName` or any other field that is specified first in the file

Here is the sample file I'm using from the documentation.

Contacts

```
FirstName,LastName
Joe,User
Jane,User
```

Here is the command I'm running

`sfdx force:data:bulk:upsert -s Contact -f data-migration/contacts.csv -i Id -w 2 -u org_of_happiness`

Can you please tell me, what's wrong?
I looked through forums and documentation and seems that my setup is correct, but for some reason it doesn't work)

I donno what's happening, hopefully, I'm just lagging really hard.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. I copied your CSV file content as well as the command as-is (changing only the csv path and org target name) and was able perform the DML successfully. Have you run 'sfdx update' lately?

Comment: Yep, I like how 2 minor version updates can break functionality completely... Had 7.68 and update to 7.70. If you want you can submit you comment as Answer

Comment: That's OK. Glad that the update solved your problem.

Comment: damn, actually it still doesn't work. It just stopped showing the error....

Comment: Could you check there are no spaces in your CSV file? The only way I was able to get the same error as you was by placing some spaces in the CSV file.

Comment: thanks, probably some system characters that are inserted by Microsoft Excel. I just copy-pasted content of the file into a new file and it solved the issue))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: That explains the problem. I saved the content as csv directly from notepad++ and didn't run into any problem. So, SFDX update might not have been really culprit.

Comment: yep, probably some hidden character from Excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same and resolved it with this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081579/bulk-api-error-invalidbatch-field-name-not-found-id

Despite the [CLI Command Reference for force:data:bulk:upsert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm?search_text=describe#cli_reference_force_data_bulk_upsert) stating "For information about formatting your CSV file, see "Prepare CSV Files" in the Bulk API Developer Guide", [which in turn states](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_csv_preparing.htm) "Files must be in UTF-8 format",
do not use this option in Excel when saving the csv file:

[image]

With the above format selected I spent some very happy times trying to resolve the "Field name not found error".

I then found the above answer, re-saved my csv using

[image]

and was able to upsert sucessfully.

Update: When saving as 'CSV UTF-8', Excel puts an invisible [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) at the start of the file.

"Its presence interferes with the use of UTF-8 by software that does not expect non-ASCII bytes at the start of a file but that could otherwise handle the text stream"

Answer (score 0):

The source issue is unknown, but after I copied content to a new file the issue was solved. Probably Excel pasted some hidden characters during the save.